# SQL Server 2012 generate script produce different result to 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012 generate script produce different result to 2008 R2
White spaces are changed
e.g. with 2008 R2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Admin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

e.g. with 2012, the extra spaces are eliminated

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Admin] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

also, in 2012, some create table scripts ends with

```
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

while the others do not have TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY], what is this?

the order of foreign key constraints is changed too.

I use SMO/SSMS to script from SQL Server 2012 and 2008 R2

These changes make "diff" 2 versions more difficult.
Any methods to deal with such changes?

Comment: Don't script with SMO (SSMS or VS), inetad use 3rd-party products such as the RedGate ones.

Comment: Does 3rd-party products such as the RedGate can script SQL server 2012 consistently same as SQL server 2008?

Comment: Maybe some settings need to be set up, but I believe so, yes; they also have products for doing proper Source Control on SQL schema and base data, which kind of requires a consistent handling across versions.

Comment: I cannot buy such products, because I am not the one to acquire external software.

Comment: I see. You can have a look at my open-source SQL Server versioning toolkit [bsn ModuleStore](http://code.google.com/p/bsn-modulestore/) which includes scripting (there were similar changes like what you're experiencing between SMO 2005 and 2008 as well, which made me switch to my own scripting). I haven't used SQL Server 2012 yet though, and the whole ModuleStore concepts also imply some limitations on the SQL code supported and the scripting abilities. Check it out, and feel free to contact me (e-mail address is in the source files) if you want to know more.